# Anybody have the 1995 Favorite Avenger Poll *full* results?

Tags: marvel, comics, avengers

I was verifying the results of the Favorite Avengers Poll from '95 and got to thinking about the full results, how (I think) I only ever saw these top 20 "reprinted" in *Avengers* #396 (March '96; on-sale, Jan 25, 1996).

[image: 1995 Favorite Avengers Poll, Top 20 - Avengers #396]

It says that many readers missed it in September's Bullpen Bulletins, but when the poll was presented in *Avengers* #387 (June '95; on-sale April 18, 1995), it said the results would be in *Avengers*' letters page (in July).

[image: 1995 Favorite Avenger Poll solicit - Avengers #387]

Now, I followed *Avengers* pretty religiously until the end a few months later, as well as many other Marvel comics (though not any other Avengers-related, solo titles), but didn't necessarily devour all things Marvel, so if a Bullpen Bulletin was ever something more than part of a book's letters page, it's true that I likely wouldn't catch it.

Does anybody know if and where it was actually published and what the other 34 results are?

Thanks.

PS: My hard-copy collection is unavailable or no longer exists, so I can't reference it, and digital editions tend to be sadly incomplete, not archival, typically lacking content like letters pages, ads, etc., so...

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to accept answers or edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.